# Using Python with Selenium to navigate Python - cannot find link?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, hyperlink, findelement

I am an accountant and very novice coder. I am trying to use Selenium with Python and Firefox browser to click through a series of webpages. I am just trying to select and click a hyperlink on the page, but I can't seem to locate it with Selenium. Please can someone show me the simplest way to select the hyperlink I want?

Imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
```

I then have code which successfully nagivates to a webpage, inputs my username and password and submits the form. Then when I want to click a link on the next page:

```
time.sleep(5) # to make sure webpage loads before trying to find link
Link1 = browser.find_element(By.partialLinkText ("/maf/app/auth")); # or any easier selector method?
Link1.click()
```

The error message is "AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'partialLinkText'"

When I inspect the link element it looks like this - not sure what the easiest element is to locate and subsequently click it?

```
<a target="_blank" title="Go to Orbitax" href="/maf/app/authentication/sso/ping/redirect?target=orbitax_chre">
Go to Orbitax 
<img src="/cpw/images/rightBlueArrow.png" alt=">" 
width="5" height="8"></a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet here

```
time.sleep(5) # to make sure webpage loads before trying to find link
Link1 = browser.find_element(By.partialLinkText ("/maf/app/auth")); # or any easier selector method?
Link1.click()
```

There is no `By.partialLinkText` in the Selenium Python bindings. It should be

```
    time.sleep(5) # to make sure webpage loads before trying to find link
    Link1 = browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "/maf/app/auth"); # or any easier selector method?
    Link1.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you are using old version of `selenium` or `import` is not work correctly.

Try to update the selenium to the latest version.

**OR**

use the below code if you are using an old version of chrome.

```
time.sleep(5)
link1 = browser.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Go to Orbitax")
link1.click()
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI I only downloaded selenium (into Mu editor) a couple of days ago. However, your code worked fine - thanks! :)

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer to help others.